# Grails Spring Security Core plugin - How do I limit concurrent sessions?

Tags: spring-security, grails-plugin

I am trying to configure Grails Spring-Security-Core plugin to limit the number of concurrent sessions that a user can have to one.  I see in the Spring Security documentation a section on Concurrent Session Control, but I can't figure out how to map that information to the Grails Spring-Security-Core configuration files?  Does anyone have an example or an approach?

Comment: You can refer to my lengthy answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35185118/2048098

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.grails.user/msg/200808142046.55494.burt@burtbeckwith.com) is dated, thus the package names would have changed and some of the steps redundant, but perhaps the technique outlined is still relevant.

Comment: Your link is dead - 404.