# Grails Spring Security max concurrent session

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have grails 2.5.1 app with spring security plugin(2.0-RC5). I would like to block the number of current session per user. I have read some blog and it doesn't work.(http://www.block-consult.com/blog/2012/01/20/restricting-concurrent-user-sessions-in-grails-2-using-spring-security-core-plugin/)
my resources.groovy

```
beans = {
  sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

    concurrencyFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter,sessionRegistry,'/main/index'){
        logoutHandlers = [ref("rememberMeServices"), ref("securityContextLogoutHandler")]
    }
    concurrentSessionControlStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = true
        maximumSessions = 1

    }
}
```

In my boostrap.groovy

```
 def init = { servletContext ->
    SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('concurrencyFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER)
  }
```

and my config.groovy I have added this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useHttpSessionEventPublisher = true
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start with, let me warn you if you decided to continue with my solution.

- **SessionRegistryImpl** is not scalable. You need to create your own scalable implementation based on your scaling plan(e.g. data grid). Session Replication just not enough.
- Currently, default logout handlers did not remove SessionRegistry properly. So i have created a sample Logout handler called **CustomSessionLogoutHandler**.
- You have to override grails spring-security-core Login Controller to handle **SessionAuthenticationException**.
- You can change number of users that can login maximumSessions = 1 to -1 for unlimited sessions.

first, in resources.groovy

```
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import com.basic.CustomSessionLogoutHandler


// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {

sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

customSessionLogoutHandler(CustomSessionLogoutHandler,ref('sessionRegistry')    )

concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry')){
    exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = true
    maximumSessions = 1
}

sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy){
    migrateSessionAttributes = true
    alwaysCreateSession = true
}
registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry'))

sessionAuthenticationStrategy(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy,[ref('concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy'),ref('sessionFixationProtectionStrategy'),ref('registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy')])

}
```

in config.groovy make sure customSessionLogoutHandler is first before securityContextLogoutHandler:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = ['customSessionLogoutHandler','securityContextLogoutHandler']
```

**ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy** uses this i18n. So you can have it in your language:

```
ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed = Maximum sessions for this principal exceeded. {0}
```

This is my sample **CustomSessionLogoutHandler** you can save it in src/groovy/com/basic/CustomSessionLogoutHandler.groovy:

```
/*
* Copyright 2002-2013 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.basic;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;

/**
 * {@link CustomSessionLogoutHandler} is in charge of removing the {@link SessionRegistry} upon logout. A
 * new {@link SessionRegistry} will then be generated by the framework upon the next request.
 *
 * @author Mohd Qusyairi
 * @since 0.1
 */
public final class CustomSessionLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {
    private final SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance
     * @param sessionRegistry the {@link SessionRegistry} to use
     */
    public CustomSessionLogoutHandler(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        Assert.notNull(sessionRegistry, "sessionRegistry cannot be null");
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the {@link SessionRegistry}
     *
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler#logout(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
     * javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
     * org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) {
        this.sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(request.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

My Sample Login Controller (I copied from the source) if you need it too. Just save as normal controller in your project as it will override the default. See line 115 below as i handle the **SessionAuthenticationException**:

```
/* Copyright 2013-2016 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.basic

import grails.converters.JSON
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

@Secured('permitAll')
class LoginController {

    /** Dependency injection for the authenticationTrustResolver. */
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver

    /** Dependency injection for the springSecurityService. */
    def springSecurityService

    /** Default action; redirects to 'defaultTargetUrl' if logged in, /login/auth otherwise. */
    def index() {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        }
        else {
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /** Show the login page. */
    def auth() {

        def conf = getConf()

        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        String postUrl = request.contextPath + conf.apf.filterProcessesUrl
        render view: 'auth', model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                                     rememberMeParameter: conf.rememberMe.parameter,
                                     usernameParameter: conf.apf.usernameParameter,
                                     passwordParameter: conf.apf.passwordParameter,
                                     gspLayout: conf.gsp.layoutAuth]
    }

    /** The redirect action for Ajax requests. */
    def authAjax() {
        response.setHeader 'Location', conf.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
        render(status: HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, text: 'Unauthorized')
    }

    /** Show denied page. */
    def denied() {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() && authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)) {
            // have cookie but the page is guarded with IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY (or the equivalent expression)
            redirect action: 'full', params: params
            return
        }

        [gspLayout: conf.gsp.layoutDenied]
    }

    /** Login page for users with a remember-me cookie but accessing a IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY page. */
    def full() {
        def conf = getConf()
        render view: 'auth', params: params,
               model: [hasCookie: authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication),
                       postUrl: request.contextPath + conf.apf.filterProcessesUrl,
                       rememberMeParameter: conf.rememberMe.parameter,
                       usernameParameter: conf.apf.usernameParameter,
                       passwordParameter: conf.apf.passwordParameter,
                       gspLayout: conf.gsp.layoutAuth]
    }

    /** Callback after a failed login. Redirects to the auth page with a warning message. */
    def authfail() {

        String msg = ''
        def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
        if (exception) {
            if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.expired')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.disabled')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.locked')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof SessionAuthenticationException){
                msg = exception.getMessage()
            }
            else {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.fail')
            }
        }

        if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
            render([error: msg] as JSON)
        }
        else {
            flash.message = msg
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /** The Ajax success redirect url. */
    def ajaxSuccess() {
        render([success: true, username: authentication.name] as JSON)
    }

    /** The Ajax denied redirect url. */
    def ajaxDenied() {
        render([error: 'access denied'] as JSON)
    }

    protected Authentication getAuthentication() {
        SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication
    }

    protected ConfigObject getConf() {
        SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this springSecurityService come from?  I have a Spring Boot/Security app that does not include it.

Comment: @Quchie in this for disable another user login with the same username?
how about disable multi login?

Comment: @akiong yes this will use username to block same user from logging in.

Comment: @sonoerin sorry this is for grails 2.x not spring boot.

Comment: @Quchie i am trying to allow same user login, but the other use will logout autatically
how?

Comment: @Quchie i am using your code, and run well, but i want chage it to allow other user to login, not block ,

Comment: @Quchie i am using grails 3. and your code run well

Comment: @akiong that is easy. I have done it before. Basically, you need to create your own authenticationStrategy and register it at sessionAuthenticationStrategy. On the onAuthentication method, make sure you delete the same user in sessionRegistry. Here is template for auth strategy: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.java

Comment: @Quchie i am trying to upgrade my code from 2x to grails 3.
when my code are like this post..
concurrencyFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter) {
  sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
  logoutHandlers = [ref("rememberMeServices"), ref("securityContextLogoutHandler")]
  expiredUrl='/login/concurrentSession'
 }

Comment: i am using expiredUrl='/login/concurrentSession'

Comment: see my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741426/grails-3-with-concurrent-session

Comment: @akiong hi, i dont think you need concurrencyFilter anymore. You can ignore expiredUrl if you remove any concurrentSessioncontrolAuthenticationStrategy. Your aim should be to remove the same users inside sessionRegistry to ensure only 1 user with the same username can login.

Comment: then what must i do? @Quchie

Comment: @Quchie i am already implement your code, where must i change?

Comment: i will make my reply there