# After upgrading to Grails 3 the sessionRegistry is empty, but authentication is working

Tags: spring-security, grails-3.0

After upgrading an old application (grails 1.3.7) to the latest grails version 3.1.3 the sessionRegistry stays empty. There were a few changes in spring security and I tried to get it working, but it looks like there is something missing... I'm using spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar

I can authenticate with spring security and it looks like everything is working. But I like to count the open sessions. I was using sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() to find open sessions, but now it is always empty.

In resources.groovy:

```
import com.myApp.LicenceCheck
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy


beans = { 
        sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl) 

        sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy){        
            it.constructorArgs = [sessionRegistry]
            maximumSessions    = -1            
        }

        concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){        
            it.constructorArgs = [sessionRegistry,'/login/concurrentSession'];
        }

        licenceCheck(LicenceCheck)          
}
```

In bootstrap.groovy:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('concurrentSessionFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER)
```

Configuration in application.groovy:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.basic.realmName='myApp'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl='/search/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm='MD5'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.myApp.Account'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.myApp.AccountAccountGroup'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.myApp.AccountGroup'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.nameField = 'role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.storeLastUsername=true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
   'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'logoutFilter',
   'authenticationProcessingFilter', 'concurrentSessionFilter',
   'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
   'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor'
]
```

After successfull authentication I'm trying to count the open sessions:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent
import grails.util.Holders

class LicenceCheck implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
         def sessionRegistry = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('sessionRegistry')
         sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() <= list is always empty
    }
}
```

This was working in the previous version (with very old grails). Now authentication is working, but sessionRegistry stays empty. Any idea what I'm missing?

Regards, grailsfan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

Problem was that the new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy (new for ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy) was not registering the session in the sessionRegistry. You have to combine different strategies with CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.

This is working for me:
[Grails Spring Security max concurrent session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827358/grails-spring-security-max-concurrent-session)