# grails 3 with concurrent session

Tags: spring, session, grails, spring-security

iam trying to upgrade my project from 2.1.1. to 3.1.1

i have some problem with concurrent session
for example..

i am login with username "AAA" on browser "chrome"
then other user is login again with username "AAA" on other browser then username "AAA" will automatically logout on browser "chrome"

..heres my code

login controller

```
package accounter

import com.vastpalaso.security.User
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@Secured('permitAll')
class LoginController {

    /** Dependency injection for the authenticationTrustResolver. */
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver

    /** Dependency injection for the springSecurityService. */
    def springSecurityService
    def cifService

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this)

    /** Default action; redirects to 'defaultTargetUrl' if logged in, /login/auth otherwise. */
    def index() {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        }
        else {
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /** Show the login page. */
    def auth() {

        def conf = getConf()

        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        String postUrl = request.contextPath + conf.apf.filterProcessesUrl
        render view: 'auth', model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                                     rememberMeParameter: conf.rememberMe.parameter,
                                     usernameParameter: conf.apf.usernameParameter,
                                     passwordParameter: conf.apf.passwordParameter,
                                     gspLayout: conf.gsp.layoutAuth]
    }

    /** The redirect action for Ajax requests. */
    def authAjax() {
        response.setHeader 'Location', conf.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
        render(status: HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, text: 'Unauthorized')
    }

    /** Show denied page. */
    def denied() {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() && authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)) {
            // have cookie but the page is guarded with IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY (or the equivalent expression)
            redirect action: 'full', params: params
            return
        }

        [gspLayout: conf.gsp.layoutDenied]
    }

    /** Login page for users with a remember-me cookie but accessing a IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY page. */
    def full() {
        def conf = getConf()
        render view: 'auth', params: params,
                model: [hasCookie: authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication),
                        postUrl: request.contextPath + conf.apf.filterProcessesUrl,
                        rememberMeParameter: conf.rememberMe.parameter,
                        usernameParameter: conf.apf.usernameParameter,
                        passwordParameter: conf.apf.passwordParameter,
                        gspLayout: conf.gsp.layoutAuth]
    }

    /** Callback after a failed login. Redirects to the auth page with a warning message. */
    def authfail() {
        def username = session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']
        String msg = ''
        def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
        if (exception) {
            if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.expired')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.disabled')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.locked')
            }
            else if (exception instanceof SessionAuthenticationException){
                msg = exception.getMessage()
                println "test"
            }
            else {
                msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.fail')
            }
        }

        try {
            boolean block = false;

            block = cifService.addTryLogin(username)
            if(session){
                render([error: msg, block: block, reload: false] as JSON)
            }
            else{
                render([error: msg, block: block, reload: true] as JSON)
            }
        }
        //catch unknown RuntimeException, redirect to Error 500 server Error page
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e)
            redirect(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
            return
        }

        if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
            render([error: msg] as JSON)
        }
        else {
            flash.message = msg
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /** The Ajax success redirect url. */
    def ajaxSuccess() {
        def user = com.vastpalaso.security.User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.authentication.name)
        def userDetails = com.vastpalaso.security.UserDetails.findByUser(user)
        def cifUsergetCif

        try{
            cifUsergetCif = com.vastpalaso.app.cif.CifUser.findByUserDetails(userDetails)
            session.setAttribute("company",cifUsergetCif.cif.corpName)
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            println "e = "+e
            println "You are loginning as admin!"
        }

        try {

            println "params = "+params
            def ipAddress = request.getHeader("Client-IP")
            if (!ipAddress) {
                ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
            }
            if (!ipAddress) {
                ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr()
            }

            try{

                cifService.resetTryLoginAddInfo(userDetails, ipAddress, session.id)
            }catch (Exception e){
                println "e = "+e
            }

            session.setAttribute("alias", userDetails.userAlias)
            session.setAttribute("fullName", userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName)
            session.setAttribute("change", userDetails.forceChangePassword)
            session.setAttribute("userType", userDetails.userType)


            if(userDetails.language != null){
                session[org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME] = new Locale(userDetails.language)
            }
            else{
                session[org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME] = new Locale("id")
            }
            buildMenuList()
            println "test = "
            if (params.callback) {
                render"${params.callback} (${[success: true,id: userDetails.id ,change: userDetails.forceChangePassword, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name, fullName: (userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName)] as JSON})"
            }
            else {
                render([success: true,id: userDetails.id, change: userDetails.forceChangePassword, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name, fullName: (userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName)] as JSON)
            }
        }
        //catch unknown RuntimeException, redirect to Error 500 server Error page
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e)
            redirect(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
            return
        }

        render([success: true, username: authentication.name] as JSON)
    }


    /** The Ajax denied redirect url. */
    def ajaxDenied() {
        render([error: 'access denied'] as JSON)
    }

    protected Authentication getAuthentication() {
        SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication
    }

    protected ConfigObject getConf() {
        SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    }

    def concurrentSession = {

        def msg = "Your account is logged in from another browser or location."

        if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
            render([error: msg] as JSON)
        }
        else {
            flash.message = msg
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }

    }
}
```

this is resouces.groovy

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import com.vastpalaso.helper.CustomSessionLogoutHandler
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter
beans = {

    sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

    customSessionLogoutHandler(CustomSessionLogoutHandler,ref('sessionRegistry'))

    concurrencyFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter) {
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
        logoutHandlers = [ref("rememberMeServices"), ref("securityContextLogoutHandler")]
        expiredUrl='/login/concurrentSession'
    }

    concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry')){
        exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = true
        maximumSessions = 1
    }

    sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy){
        migrateSessionAttributes = true
        alwaysCreateSession = true
    }
    registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry'))

    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy,[ref('concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy'),ref('sessionFixationProtectionStrategy'),ref('registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy')])


    jmsConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) { brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61616" }
}
```

and this is my code where  i copy from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827358/grails-spring-security-max-concurrent-session/35185118?noredirect=1#comment66779414_35185118)

```
package com.vastpalaso.helper;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;

/**
 * {@link CustomSessionLogoutHandler} is in charge of removing the {@link SessionRegistry} upon logout. A
 * new {@link SessionRegistry} will then be generated by the framework upon the next request.
 *
 * @author Mohd Qusyairi
 * @since 0.1
 */
public final class CustomSessionLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {
    private final SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance
     * @param sessionRegistry the {@link SessionRegistry} to use
     */
    public CustomSessionLogoutHandler(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        Assert.notNull(sessionRegistry, "sessionRegistry cannot be null");
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the {@link SessionRegistry}
     *
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler#logout(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
     * javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
     * org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       Authentication authentication) {
        this.sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(request.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Quchie heres my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will expire currently logged in user (same username and password). The new user can continue to login without any issue.

Create new implementation of SessionAuthenticationStrategy by adding this to src folder. In **grails 3, (src/main/groovy) in grails (2.x src/groovy)**.
I call this a custom name based on what you want to achieve save this as **ConcurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy.groovy**:

```
    package com.myapp.test;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
    import org.springframework.util.Assert;
    import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
    import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

    /**
     * Strategy used to register a user with the {@link SessionRegistry} after successful
     * {@link Authentication}.
     *
     * <p>
     * {@link RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy} is typically used in combination with
     * {@link CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy} and
     * {@link ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy}, but can be used on its own if
     * tracking of sessions is desired but no need to control concurrency.
     *
     * <p>
     * NOTE: When using a {@link SessionRegistry} it is important that all sessions (including
     * timed out sessions) are removed. This is typically done by adding
     * {@link HttpSessionEventPublisher}.
     *
     * @see CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy
     *
     * @author Luke Taylor
     * @author Rob Winch
     * @since 3.2
     */
    public class ConcurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy implements
            SessionAuthenticationStrategy {
        private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

        /**
         * @param sessionRegistry the session registry which should be updated when the
         * authenticated session is changed.
         */
        public ConcurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
            Assert.notNull(sessionRegistry, "SessionRegistry cannot be null");
            this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
        }
        /**
         * In addition to the steps from the superclass, the sessionRegistry will be removing
         * with the new session information.
         */
        public void onAuthentication(Authentication authentication,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            def sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(
                    authentication.getPrincipal(), false);

            def principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()
            sessions.each{
                if(it.principal == authentication.getPrincipal()){
                    it.expireNow()
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

In **resources.groovy**:

```
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
    import com.myapp.test.ConcurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter
    // Place your Spring DSL code here
    beans = {
            sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)
            //I see you did not have this. Very dangerous!
            sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy){
                migrateSessionAttributes = true
                alwaysCreateSession = true
            }
            //Initiate the bean
            concurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry'))
            registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry'))
            sessionAuthenticationStrategy(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy,[ref('concurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy'),ref('sessionFixationProtectionStrategy'),ref('registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy')])
            concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter,ref('sessionRegistry'))
    }
```

In config, finally add this line:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [ 'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'logoutFilter', 'concurrentSessionFilter', 'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter', 'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor' ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in grails 3 , i dont need to add something to config.groovy, because grails 3 doesnt have config.groovy @Quchie

Comment: hey..your code run well..btw how can i change this "This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being attempted as the same user)."

Comment: You can use application.groovy or .yml .application.groovy is same as config.groovy in grails 2.x

Comment: i try put this code `grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = ['securityContextPersistenceFilter','concurrentSessionFilter','anonymousAuthenticationFilter', 'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor']` in application.groovy, but my login doesnot work

Comment: i tried to delete that line, and it works ,i dont know why :D

Comment: @akiong you can add a redirect url by having set expiredUrl like this: concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter,ref('sessionRegistry'),'/userExpiredUrl')

Comment: make sure the url is accessible by the public (anonymous)

Comment: @akiong it didnt work because there are missing filters. Refer to docs to see what is missing :)

Comment: then i need this line `SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('concurrencyFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER)` right?

Comment: @akiong sure this is one way to do it. You can add this at bootstrap.groovy

Comment: didyou mean i miss thi s`authenticationProcessingFilter` in filternames?

Comment: `grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
  'ConcurrentSingleSessionAuthenticationStrategy',
  'securityContextPersistenceFilter',
  'concurrentSessionFilter',
  'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
  'exceptionTranslationFilter',
  'filterInvocationInterceptor',
  'sessionRegistry','sessionFixationProtectionStrategy'
]`

Comment: but must i put `grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames` to applicaion.groovy?

Comment: yes you are right. if it runs well, then great! I feel its best to define your filterchain as it will be easier to debug later :)

Comment: @Quchie I adopted your solution (so thanks for that), but I noted a side effect: Spring Security is unable to re-generate user session from the rememberMe cookie value, if present.
Is there a way to allow that as well? I haven't dived deeply enough into Spring Security to be able to tell..

Comment: @ilPittiz Current filters does not have that, Maybe you could add it? You need to make sure the Filters(http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.html) for that exist in the filterChain.FilterNames properties. I have not try this..

Comment: Ah yes! After a few attempts I came up with `grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [ 'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'logoutFilter', 'concurrentSessionFilter', 'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter', 'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor' ]` that is working properly for my case. I also added `logoutFilter`, not included in previous solutions and required to have logout work as expected.